# how can i search and replace a non-character in a string in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following format data

```
$line1 = violation:start:CLK:a1.ID:end:a2.VALUE[22:0]:CLK1
$line2 = violation:start:CLK2:b1.ID[23:45]:end:b2.VALUE[2:03]:CLK3
```

So, how can i search and replace [\d+:\d+] with [\d+#\d+]

For example: [22:0] to [22#0]

Please help me!

Comment: Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/G5RVtd/2/)

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. What you have written is not valid perl.

Comment: A string contains characters and nothing else. There are no non-characters in your example, and there is no way for a string to contain something which isn't a character.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
my $line1 = 'violation:start:CLK:a1.ID:end:a2.VALUE[22:0]:CLK1';
my $line2 = 'violation:start:CLK2:b1.ID[23:45]:end:b2.VALUE[2:03]:CLK3';
for ($line1, $line2) {
    s/\[ (\d+) : (\d+) \]/[$1#$2]/gmsx;
}
print "$line1\n$line2\n";
__END__
violation:start:CLK:a1.ID:end:a2.VALUE[22#0]:CLK1
violation:start:CLK2:b1.ID[23#45]:end:b2.VALUE[2#03]:CLK3
```